# What is the difference between different ad providers for Windows Store Apps?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I've developed a Windows Store App which is ad supported. After struggling quite a bit with the actual implementation and testing locally, I (think I) managed to make it work - using the test ids provided by Microsoft my local tests showed the example ad.

After I uploaded the app to the store, however, I get the NoAdsAvailable message (I did use the correct ApplicationId and AdUnitId, not the test ones), indicating that there are no ads of the specified category available at my geographic location (it is my understanding that this is how Microsoft differentiates which ads should be shown where).

Now what I would like to know is which of the different ad rotator solutions is recommended to be used - or is this too dependent on where I live?

I've found the following three alternatives:

- [AdRotator](http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/adrotator-for-windows-8)
- [AdDuplex](http://www.adduplex.com/)
- [AdMob](https://www.google.com/admob/)

Does anyone have any experience in using them? What are the differences? Just using the pubCenter ads from Microsoft doesn't seem to be the best option as various posts I've found indicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've discovered is that ad providers won't always have an ad available to show every time you want one. This is called the "fill rate". Depending on the ad provider, the app category and where in the world the person viewing it is, this can vary dramatically. Somewhere between 10 and 40% can be seen as normal.

Your intention to use a tool to include support for multiple ad providers is a common approach to this scenario.
There are 2 tools that you can consider: [AdRotator](http://getadrotator.com/); and [AdMediator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/401703a0-263e-4949-8f0f-738305d6ef4b) ([video](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/11/11/inside-windows-platform-maximize-ad-revenue-with-windows-ad-mediator-service-and-control/))

**AdRotator** is a mature, community provided service which supports a wider range of ad providers.
**AdMediator** is newer and provided by Microsoft. It is integrated with the Windows Dev Center but is only available in limited locations.

Both allow you to set a number of ad providers to use on a fall-back basis. If the first doesn't have an ad it tries the next, and so on.

AdDuplex is different to PubCenter, AdMob or the other advertising providers in that it is a cross promotion service. You show ads for other apps and they show ads for yours. For every 10 ads you show, 8 ads are shown for your app. The other two spaces are sold to fund the service.
Due to the way it works, AdDuplex always has an ad for you to show, so even if you can't show an ad that will earn you money, you can show an ad that will lead to an ad for your own app being shown. Hopefully this will lead to more users for your app which will in turn lead to more money earned from ads shown in the future.
Whichever ad providers you use, it makes sense to always include AdDuplex as a final option with either AdRotator or AdMediator so that, as long as you have a network connection, you are always making use of the space in your app that you've allocated for ad space.

**Disclaimer** - I'm an advocate for AdDuplex.

Comment: Thank you, I wil try to implement using fall back solution with AdDuplex at the lowest level.